# Data structure with init $O(n)$ and interval max $O(\log n)$

Tags: data-structures

I need to find a data structure that supports the following operations:

- init(A): gets an array of size $n$ of different numbers and builds the data structure - should be $O(n)$.
- max(i,j): gets two indexes $i<j$ and returns the maximum value between these two cells, that is, $A[i],A[i+1],\dots,A[j]$ - should be $O(\log n)$.

It should be a tree related data structure.

Comment: What are your thoughts? Have you tried solving this problem on your own? How far did you get?

Comment: You may use [Segment Trees](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/min-max-range-queries-array/)!

Answer (score 2):

Assume for simplicity that $n$ is a power of 2. Construct a complete binary tree in which the vertices at depth $k$ correspond to subarrays of length $n/2^k$, and contain as auxiliary information the maximum element of the subarray.

This data structure can be initialized in $O(n)$, and it supports your type of range queries in $O(\log n)$. You can also update the data structure by modifying arbitrarily a single element of the array in $O(\log n)$.

Details left to you.

Comment: Thanks, actually I came to this notion of using a tournament tree, but couldn't figure out how to find the max between 2 indexes that are not excactly signify start and end of a subarray, say 3-4. I mean, they do, but if a got it right I don't have a vertice that holds that max value exactly

Comment: Right, there is still some work left to do.

Comment: ok, I guess it has something to do with some comparisons between some vertices to determain this kind of max values